# Firebase data is being written incorrectly

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a wrong data written to firebase

[image: Here's an image of my issue]

When I add data it is being saved to "0" child path.

Here's the code which adds this data to Firebase:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
        var uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid.toString()
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        var ct: AddProductsItem = listFiltered[position]
        holder.productName.text = ct.content
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context)
            .load(ct.image)
            .into(holder.productImage)
        rv.setOnClickListener {
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(con)

            builder.setTitle(holder.productName.text)

            var finalProduct = mutableListOf<AddProductsItem>(ct)
            var name = ct.content
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to add this product?")

            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes"){ _, _ ->
                database.child("users").child(uid).child("products").push().setValue(finalProduct)
                Toast.makeText(this.con,"Added product to your list",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            builder.setNeutralButton("No"){_,_ ->
                Toast.makeText(this.con,"Cancelled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

            dialog.show()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is doing exactly what your code told it to do.  You're calling `setValue(finalProduct)` and `finalProduct` is an array:

```
var finalProduct = mutableListOf<AddProductsItem>(ct)
```

Since you wrote an array, Firebase is adding array indexes to the data - that's why you have a 0 in the path.  If you don't want that 0, then don't write an array.  Write the single element `ct` instead.